# selected dropdown change not working in Edge browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a selected option select items and using jquery on change to update a search. The functionality works in IE11 but not edge. In Edge, after the first item is selected the change event doesn't work after that. If I select from the last item, it will change, but as soon as the first item on the list is selected, the change event doesn't work anymore. Below is a portion of my code.

```js
    $("#btn-search").click(function () {
            const comingDue = parseInt($("#comingDueIds option:selected").val(), 10);
            const duedate = new Date();
            duedate.setDate(duedate.getDate() + comingDue);
            const duesdates =   Date.parse(duedate);
            function dropdownUpdate() {
                $('.table tbody tr').each(function () {
                    const comingDates = $(this).find('td').eq(2);
                    const dates =comingDates[0].childNodes[2].innerText;
                    const DueDate = Date.parse(dates);
                    $(this).toggle(DueDate <= duesdates );
                });
            }
            $('#comingDueIds').on('change', dropdownUpdate);
            dropdownUpdate();
       
      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="comls" id="comingDueIds" style="width: 140px;">
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Days</option>
                                <option value="5">5 Days</option>
                                <option value="10">10 Days</option>
                                <option value="15">15 Days</option>
                                <option value="20">20 Days</option>
                                <option value="25">25 Days</option>
                            </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put **dropdownUpdate** and the event handler that calls it outside of the click handler. You are going to have weird problems when putting it inside of the click handler.

If you require the btn-search to be clicked, you can always add some sort of if statement for a variable. But you don't need it in there.

```
function dropdownUpdate() {
  $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
    const comingDates = $(this).find('td').eq(2);
    const dates = comingDates[0].childNodes[2].innerText;
    const DueDate = Date.parse(dates);
    $(this).toggle(DueDate <= duesdates);
  });
}

$("#btn-search").click(function() {
  const comingDue = parseInt($("#comingDueIds option:selected").val(), 10);
  const duedate = new Date();
  duedate.setDate(duedate.getDate() + comingDue);
  const duesdates = Date.parse(duedate);
});

$('#comingDueIds').on('change', dropdownUpdate);
dropdownUpdate();
```